# How to make conditional attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes

I want to hide some member vars in my C# class.
I can do this via the DebuggerBrowsable attribute:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[DebuggerBrowsable(System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
int myvar;
```

However, I only want this attribute to be applied for Release builds - I want to hide the var from my assembly's Release-build consumers but I want the var visible in Debug builds for inspection during dev, etc.

I could, but would prefer not to, wrap each attribute in an #if block:

```
#if !DEBUG
        [DebuggerBrowsable(System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
#endif
```

That would do the trick, but creates some pretty messy-looking code.

If I were in C++/CLI - and had macros - I could do this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define HIDDEN_MEMBER
#else
#define HIDDEN_MEMBER   [System::Diagnostics::DebuggerBrowsableAttribute(System::Diagnostics::DebuggerBrowsableState::Never)]
#endif
```

and then

```
HIDDEN_MEMBER
int myvar;
```

But no macros in C# :(

Any bright ideas as to how to achieve the macro-like syntax in C#?

Answer (score 2):

See the [ConditionalAttribute class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx), you can apply the `[Conditional]` attribute to the `[DebuggerBrowsable]` attribute.

Comment: You'll need to demonstrate how that can work.  It certainly won't compile in the OP's example.

Comment: AFAIK, this answer is factually incorrect. While one can only apply the `ConditionalAttribute` to the *definition* of another attribute class, it cannot be applied to a particular *instance* of that attribute; i.e. one would require control over the the source code of the target attribute. But `DebuggerBrowsableAttribute` is part of the framework.

Comment: well, the OP said "bright ideas", this just happens to be a bright idea that doesn't actually work!  stakx is right, I should have tested the OP's code in stead of relying on my understanding of the doc.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
const bool debugging = true;
```

And then

```
[DebuggerBrowsableAttribute(debugging ? DebuggerBrowsableState.Collapsed
                                      : DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```

Comment: +1 This will work (but you switched the expressions in the conditional operator); `const bool debugging = true;` could be rewritten as 
`#if DEBUG
        const bool debugging = true;
#else
        const bool debugging = false;
#endif` and there you go

Comment: OK, I swapped the two options.

Answer (score 1):

Just another suggestion, using a type alias:

```
#if DEBUG
using HiddenMember = global::DummyAttribute.HiddenMember;
#else
using HiddenMember = global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute;
#endif

namespace DummyAttribute
{
    class HiddenMember : Attribute
    { public HiddenMember(DebuggerBrowsableState dummy) { } }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class YourClass
{
    [HiddenMember(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    int YourMember = 0;
}
```

Feel free to hide the `DebuggerBrowsableState.Never` argument behind a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that I came up with, which I like:

```
In the base class:
#if DEBUG
   [DebuggerBrowsable(System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
   internal const System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState BROWSABLE_ATTRIB = System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Collapsed;
#else
   [DebuggerBrowsable(System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
   internal const System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState BROWSABLE_ATTRIB = System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Never;
#endif
```

which works for me because all my objects have a common base, however deep it may be.
Note that I'm hiding BROWSABLE_ATTRIB... I don't want that const publicly visible.

Then in any derived class:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(BROWSABLE_ATTRIB)]
int myvar;
```

I prefer this to @Olivier's answer, though I thank him kindly for posting it.
While a ternary in each attribute is better then the **#if #else #endif** mess, it's still more verbose than I'd prefer.

I was also unaware of **ConditionalAttribute**; thanks @Tony for that. While it may not solve this particular situation I can see how it could be very useful in others and I'm grateful to add it to my bag of tricks.